# Significance in ostream or fprintf in C++

Tags: c++, printf, ostream, significant-digits

I'm trying to get an output to file such as this:

```
1.11111
11.1111
111.111
1111.11
111111
```

In other words, I try to set the significance of my output, instead of my precision. I've tried

```
oFile <<setprecision(6);
```

and

```
fprintf(oFile, "%6f", varName);
```

To no avail.

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers

EDIT: Sorry for the incomplete question. Here's a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    ofstream oFile("output.dat");
    float var1 = 10.9993;
    float var2 = 11;
    oFile << var1 << endl;
    oFile << var2 << endl;
    oFile << std::setprecision(6) << var2 - var1 <<endl; //10.9993 - 11 = -0.000699997
    oFile.close();
    /* 
     * output
     * 10.9993
     * 11
     * 0.000699997
    */
    FILE * oFile2;
    oFile2 = fopen("output2.dat","w");
    fprintf(oFile2, "%6f \n%6f \n%6f \n",var1, var2, var2-var1);
    fclose(oFile2);
    /*
     * output
     * 10.999300 
     * 11.000000 
     * 0.000700 
    */
}
```

So I want to have at most 6 significant digits in every case, regardless of the precision, i.e:

```
10.9993
11 or 11.0000 that does not matter
0.00070
```

OK, so I've ended up multiplying each variable out of decimal points, subtracted and divided back into decimal points. This seems to work. Crazy that there does not seem to be a functionality to set significance in C++.

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Isn't there a missing `11111.1` ?

Comment: _'To no avail.'_ Is a much too vague _question_ for SO :/ ...

Comment: My code produces the results you want, except that the final '0' is missing from `0.0007`, but that should be the same "don't care" as the second case.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you asked for, but I managed to get the result

```
1.11111
11.1111
111.111
1111.11
11111.1
111111
```

with the following code :

```
double test=1.11111;
for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
{
    cout<<test<<endl;
    test*=10;
}
```

No need for iomanip or changing any precision for this case.

Comment: What happens if you add a few digits to each double?

Comment: Then iomanip will be needed. You simply count the total number of digits and use that in cout<<setprecision(num_of_digits) and instead of j<6 you put j<num_of_digits

Comment: This does not limit the number of significant digits. Required is to output (e.g.) `1.23456` from, say `1.23456789`. And how do you propose to "count the total number of [decimal] digits" in a double that's the result of some computation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is code that sets the double values with more digits than you want to be displayed, and two techniques to get what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  double d[6] = { 1.1111123, 11.111123, 111.11123,
                  1111.1123, 11111.123, 111111.23 };

  for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
    std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << d[i] << std::endl;
  }

  for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ){
    char buf[20];
    sprintf( buf, "%6g", d[i] );
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
  }
  {
    char buf[20];
    sprintf( buf, "%6g", d[1]-d[0] );
    std::cout << buf << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Can be improved, but it shows the basic ingredients.

**Later**

```
d[0] = 10.9993;
d[1] = 11;
d[2] = d[1] - d[0];
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
  std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << d[i] << std::endl;
}
std::cout << std::setprecision(6) << d[1]-d[0] << std::endl;

for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
  char buf[20];
  sprintf( buf, "%6g", d[i] );
  std::cout << buf << std::endl;
}
```

This produces

```
10.9993
11
0.0007
0.0007
10.9993
    11
0.0007
0.0007
```

Comment: When I adapt your code to my use case, it does not work when I subtract the values (var2 - var1).

Comment: Your implementation works now. It seems I should use doubles instead of floats... don't know why though... However when I use this functionality in the context of my code it breaks down again.